# Powershell variable in file name

Tags: powershell

Everyday a file is being saved with the current date in format `testDDMMYYY.csv` for an example `test24112017.csv`.

I need to open the current day's file with Powershell, however, I haven't found a way for it to work with variables.

```
#Date (24112017)
[String]$a=(Get-Date).ToShortDateString() | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\.", ""} 

#Open the file called test24112017
[int] $S1=Get-Content "D:\test$($a).csv" -Tail 1 |  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`"", ""} | ForEach-Object{$_.Split(",")[1]} | write-host
```

How can I get that variable working inside that path?

Comment: Can you not just do "get-content "D:\test$a.csv"

Comment: I can confirm what @Joseph says. It works with just "D:\test$a.csv".

Comment: I thought so too, but I have 2 files for testing "test.csv" and "test24112017.csv" . Using "D:\test$a.csv displays the contents of "test.csv"

Comment: You can simply use : `Get-Content "D:\test$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy').csv" -Tail 1`

Comment: Thank You! This works perfectly!

Comment: Also, you probably want to take out the "write-host" at the end of your piped statement.

Comment: @Kaspar I just posted an answer, as it's ok, you can mark the answer as accepted for the others who could have the same question

Comment: Wow, when I added my last comment, it finally showed the other comments. Weird. Also, did you confirm that $a had what you think it had? It sounds like, from your last comment, it had a null value. Your -replace statement may have had something to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `(Get-Date).ToShortDateString() | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\.", ""}`, just use `Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy'` to format the date the way you want :

```
Get-Content "D:\test$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy').csv" -Tail 1
```

[Formatting Dates and Times](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm aren't you over-complicating things a bit?

First of all,
`(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()` doesn't give me `24112017` but `24-11-2017`.
So i'm guessing we have different regional settings, what part of the world are you from?

Have you printed out `$a`? What does it give you?

I would go for a different approach. Since your filename is literally always newer than the previous one (because it holds a date).
I would just sort on the Name and select the first one (aka the newest file).

```
$newestfile = Get-ChildItem c:\temp |  Sort-Object Name -Desc | select * -First 1
```

Now go do whatever you want with your latest file.

```
get-content $newestfile.fullname
```